# How to change Description tab title

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, frontend

Hope You All doing good. I am using magento 1.9 with Porto Theme . I want to change tile of 'Description ' to 'Details' in product page . Any one know how to do it ? how can i change description tabs title ? and related products are not showing , what should i do for display related products?

Comment: check this links --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26486275/11908692 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/12490079/11908692

Comment: Welcome @Syze Developer

Answer (score 1):

Goto app/design/frontend/Theme_Name/default/layout/catalog.xml

check this code

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
 </block>
```

Replace the name "Description"  to your desired name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer which is true but in my case go to

> app/design/frontend/Theme_Name/default/layout/local.xml

and replace desired content in between `<value></value>` options